Script to enable 'Track Changes in Current Story' and 'Show Changes'
I have a requirement to enable the 'Track Changes in Current Story' and 'Show Changes' settings of Adobe InCopy when a document is opened in InCopy.
The user does not want to click on these two settings manually; the script must automatically turn them on when it runs.
I have tried the 'afterOpen' event in a script placed in the startup scripts folder, but this event always seems to fire before the document is completely loaded, so when I do use it I get an error that states the object is no longer available and a prompt to ask me if I would like to disable the event handler (which I do not)
Furthermore, it seems that it is impossible to turn on 'Show Changes' (View menu > Show Changes) programmatically via Extendscript. You can change everything about how any changes appear (IE changed, added, deleted text etc) but it does not seem possible to enable the 'Show Changes' setting.
The only other way I have been able to turn on 'Show Changes' is by building up a string of Visual Basic that emulates a user clicking the View > Show Changes option, but that is not a solution as it would mean this is then turned off and on every time a new document is opened. I need it switched on so that it can not be turned off again
The script below will switch on the 'Track Changes in Current Story' option, but it does not seem as simple to do the same for 'Show Changes'.
toggleTrackChanges();

function toggleTrackChanges()
{
    
    try {
        
        if (app.documents.length > 0) {
            var doc = app.activeDocument;
            
            // Select the first body story instead of header or other sections
            var mainStory = doc.stories[1]; // You can adjust this index to target specific stories if needed
            
             if (mainStory) {
                // Select the first insertion point (cursor position) in the main story
                app.select(mainStory.insertionPoints[0]);
                
                // Enable track changes for the selected story
                app.activeDocument.stories.everyItem().trackChanges = true;
                **app.activeDocument.stories.everyItem().showChanges = true;**
             }
             else {
                 alert("No stories found in the document.");
             }
            
        }

    } catch (myErrorMessage){
        alert('Could not apply track changes');
    }

}

My questions:

Can anyone tell me how I can toggle on the 'Show Changes' setting just as I have done above? I thought it would be simply enough to use app.activeDocument.stories.everyItem().showChanges, but InCopy does not have a method/property for showChanges
Which event do I need to use to make this run AFTER a document has completely loaded in InCopy? Currently the 'afterOpen' event seems the most appropriate but it still seems to fire before a document is completely loaded

Thanks

I'm not an expert. Just a guess. If there is a way to toggle the 'Show changes' via menu actions? Something like:
app.menuActions.itemByID(###).invoke()

Where ### is a ID of the action.
The list of menu actions you can probably get with this script:
for (var i=0; i<app.menuActions.length; i++) {
    var m = app.menuActions[i];
    list += m.id + "\t" + m.name + "\t" + m.area + "\n";
}

f = File("menu_actions.txt");
f.encoding = "UTF-8";
f.open("w");
f.write(list);
f.close();

f.execute();

alert(i + " actions wese saved to " + f.fsName);

As for the event 'afterOpen' as far as I remember in InDesign, there are some glitches. It runs twice sometimes. And you have to use '#targetengine' always. This script works in my InDesigh:
#targetengine 'onAfterOpen'

var myApplicationEventListener = app.eventListeners.add('afterOpen', myfunc);

function myfunc(e) {
    // prevent the script  to run twice
    if (e.target.constructor.name !== 'Document') exit();

    var doc = e.parent;
    try { 
        main(doc);
    } catch(e) { 
        var msg = e + ' -> ' + e.line; 
        $.writeln(msg) 
    }
}

function main() {
    // do something
}

Again, it's InDesign. I don't know if it will work in InCopy the same way. Just a guess.
